# Unable to set this Response Entity method

Tags: java, entity, response

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "MyHystrixCommand", fallbackMethod = "myHystrixFallback", threadPoolKey = "ThreadPoolKey")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getServiceCallResponse(String serviceUrl, HttpEntity<?> entity) {
    ResponseEntity<String> resp = null;
    try {
        resp = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class)
                        .getBody();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        handleExceptionForHystrix("getServiceCallResponse", e);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Getting error when setting resp saying it's a mismatch. Unable to understand why it's going on. What can be the alternative.

Comment: Apologies for not formatting.

Comment: See [Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [How to format code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Thanks James. Any idea what's wrong in the code?